# Using FastReport.Net together wit DELPHI-XE6

Tags: delphi, fastreport

Today we use ChrystalReport with DELPHI but now we are planning to move into FastReport.
As we have a lot reports we also found FatReportServer interesting but at a closer look this product looks to have come to a deadend. They don't develop it more.
Instead they refer to FastReport.Net.

Now I wonder if there is a way you can use the .net-version from DELPHI without need for .net programming?

Here's the link to [my source:](http://fast-report.com/en/forum/index.php?showtopic=11240).

Comment: Are you sure they've ended VCL development ? I believe they would mention it somewhere and at least the [`product page`](http://goo.gl/nFCSzr) doesn't say so.

Comment: They just published Fast-Report 5 for VCL like a few weeks back. Could you please quote where you got it's discontinued?

Comment: Fast Reports VCL version has not been discontinued and can be seen on the Fast Reports web-site by clicking on the Products link and selecting the "Fast Reports VCL" button.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean the VCL-FastReport -- I meant the FastReport Server product which is a bit different.

Comment: Gunter The Beutiful: I added the link above at the original question. Please have a look ;-)